# Rewrite Rules return 404 error with new version of UwAmp

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, uwamp

I installed UwAmp 2.0 and everything worked ok, and then I decided to install UwAmp 3.0.2.

However, now the Rewrite Rules do not work.

This one, for instance, returns a 404 error:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /category.php?label=$1 [L]
```

when accessing http://foo.test/mycategory/
(it works ok if I acess http://foo.test/category.php?label=mycategory).

These are the contents of the Apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
#UWAMP Generate Virtual Host
    DocumentRoot "C:\Uwamp-3-0-2\web"
    ServerName "foo.test"
    <Directory "C:\Uwamp-3-0-2\web">
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm not sure about what I am doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Manual apache configuration is required.

Config file for apache: 
`bin/apache/conf/httpd_uwamp.conf`

Find the following line:
`#LoadModule rewrite_module "{APACHEPATH}/modules/mod_rewrite.so"`

Remove the `#`. Save the file and restart Apache.